# Azure DevOps Update Variable Inside Code Before Deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-devops, devops

Is it possible for Azure DevOps to update part of my code when release kicks in?

For example, I have a setting file inside my react app. This setting file has `export const ISPROD = false` in it. I need Azure DevOps to change this false value to true before it builds the react app and deploys it. Is that possible?

Note: My Server build is Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update your code in your javascript files using the "[Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)" task e.g.

```
- task: replacetokens@3
    inputs:
      targetFiles: "yourJavascriptFile.js"
      encoding: "auto"
      writeBOM: true
      verbosity: "detailed"
      actionOnMissing: "warn"
      keepToken: false
      tokenPrefix: "#{"
      tokenSuffix: "}#"
    displayName: Perform variable substitution in javascript file file
```

You'd add this task before the task you use to build your application.

In your javascript file you would write the variables to be replaced as e.g.

```
export const ISPROD = #{IS_PROD}#
```

This task when run would then replace "#{IS_PROD}#" with your Azure Devops variable named "IS_PROD" with it's value set as true.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on linux you can just add the [bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) or [shell script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script?view=azure-devops) to your build and add an inline script or path to a script in your repo that does the setting update.

You'll need to take a look at the [available environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) in your pipeline that you can use in your script to access the working directory of your code.

You can optionally specify [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) under which the task runs. For example, I do something very similar when versioning our components for release, which are only done during builds triggered by a git tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a free Visual Studio Marketplace Pipeline task that will do the trick: [Replace Text in Source Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Samayas.azuredevops-samayas-replaceinfiles)

This one will also work: [RegexReplace Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=knom.regexreplace-task)

Comment: Thank you @TrevorBrooks, these are great options for Windows Build Servers. Mine is Linux.

Comment: These are two other options that may work.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=citrus-andriessen.cag-replace-tokens

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a custom solution following might help full to you

1. Go with Bash Task in azure pipeline
2. In Yaml steps define inline  Ex: 
   steps:

   - task: Bash@ReplaceTextInFile
     inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script:   bashscript
3. use sed command to replace text in your file.

Comment: You're a savior muni. Thanks for this solution. It worked perfectly